# How do I control IntelliJ Idea autoformat bracket placement for (Java) lambdas?

Tags: intellij-idea

Without going into the politics of the company, I need to change the behaviour of the IntelliJ Java formatter thus....

```
someMethod(() -> {
   // do stuff
}
```

Needs to format to:

```
 someMethod(() -> 
 {
    // do stuff
 }
```

I got it moving { to new line for regular methods :( but struggling to find the option to do same for lambdas.

Comment: Did you check with live templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java** > 'Wrapping and Braces' tab > 'Braces placement' section > 'In lambda declaration' option > set to 'Next line' instead of default 'End of line'.

[image]